# How to use the jquery variable in script inside the PHP tag echo?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am getting the issue

> Warning: Use of undefined constant otherInput - assumed 'otherInput'
> (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) Warning: A
> non-numeric value encountered

I know there is some issue with the quote.

What I am doing is, I have to click on the anchor tag called `Click me one` and sending the data-id in the script. I am getting the id value in the script but I am getting the error on `$(".showme'+otherInput+'").show();`

I am using WordPress and I have to use the below code in the function.php so I have to use my script inside the PHP tag.

This is the screenshot of the code
[image]

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
         .showme{display: none;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="clickme" data-id="1">Click me one</div>
      <div class="showme showme1">this is example</div>
      <?php
         echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(".clickme").click(function(){
             var otherInput=$(this).data("id");  
               $(".showme'+otherInput+'").show();
               });.
         </script>';
         ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the regular js standard, and if you willing to implement your script inside the php code:

Replace your code with these changes:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
           <head>
              <title></title>
              <style type="text/css">
                 .showme{display: none;}
              </style>
           </head>
           <body>
              <div class="clickme" data-id="1">Click me one</div>
              <div class="showme showme1">this is example</div>
              <?php
         echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(".clickme").click(function(){
                var otherInput=$(this).data("id");  
                $(".showme"+otherInput).show(); 
                
                //here otherInput js variable is just used as regular js variable inside the script, so no need to extra commas to call that js variable, just use it like you do in js files, and will work fine.
             });
         </script>';
         ?>

           </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You're pretty much saying what I said.  So why does the OP need the `echo` at all?

Comment: your suggestion is just to use js code and you haven't mentioned the replacement in echo, so I just mentioned that in echo. I'm not saying what you are saying, I'm saying what I tested.

Comment: @paulsm4, I need in echo because my whole code is in the echo and this code is the one part of my code.

Comment: @RajenderVerma, After adding your code, If I refresh the page then I am getting the same error.

Comment: @user9437856 what error r u getting? can you add that here.

Comment: @RajenderVerma, Warning: Use of undefined constant otherInput - assumed 'otherInput' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: @user9437856 you tried my answer, as I tested it and it's working fine without that error that you were getting.

Comment: @RajenderVerma, Can you add your whole answer?

Comment: @user9437856 I updated my answer. Sorry about my new answer, I forgot to edit existing one. so above is my whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything in your php block is all JQuery/Javascript.

Q: What do you even need the PHP block and the "echo" for?

Current:

```
  <?php
     echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(".clickme").click(function(){
            var otherInput=$(this).data("id");  
            $(".showme'+otherInput+'").show();
         });.
     </script>';
     ?>
```

Suggested change:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".clickme").click(function(){
         var otherInput=$(this).data("id");  
         $(".showme"+otherInput).show();
      });.
  </script>'
```

Comment: This `$(".showme'+otherInput+'").show();` should be `$(".showme"+otherInput).show();` .

Comment: @Swati - thank you for the correction.  It's also possible tht "showme" is a server-side (PHP) constant or variable, and the "." is PHP string concatenation.  In which case it might be `$(" <?php showme ?>otherInput).show();`.  But as far as I can tell, there's *NO* PHP in the block, and no need for the "echo".  Which was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @paulsm4, I checked your first one answer. I am still getting the error when I reload the page.